# How to use multiple Python Variables in an SQL Query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, variables

At the moment, I'm trying to use query a mySQL database with Python variables. I understand the convention for using variables in a query are as follows:

```
curr.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

However, the query I want to execute is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE City = (cityName)
AND AdmissionDate BETWEEN (startDate) AND (endDate)
```

I'm not sure how the variables would need to be formatted, whether they all need to be in the 1 tuple or I can format it as I would in a printf statement so I'm not sure which of the below would be correct:

```
curr.execute("SELECT * FROM table1
              WHERE City = (%s)
              AND AdmissionDate BETWEEN (%s) AND (%s)",(cityName, startDate, endDate))


curr.execute("SELECT * FROM table1
              WHERE City = (%s)
              AND AdmissionDate BETWEEN (%s) AND (%s)", (cityName), (startDate), (endDate))
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always `print(your query)` and test it out.

Comment: What happens when you run either statement ? Hint: that may give you the answer.